# Synaptics Touchpad Behaving Strangely

Tags: windows-vista, synaptics-touchpad

My touchpad has suddenly become unusable. I can move the cursor with it, but clicking with the left mouse button seems to have little effect. When I drag the cursor over text, it seems to highlight the text automatically, only letting go of the highlight randomly. It also seems to automatically drag any draggable items it moves over. In addition, if I simply place it onto a folder or something, the folder will, after a short period of time, possibly open by itself.

To solve this, I've tried updating the Synaptics driver from Device Manager (there is no update), uninstalling Synaptics, re-installing Synaptics, swapping the buttons, turning on and off the tap features, touch zones, rebooting, Safe Mode, etc. None of it has corrected the problem since it originally occurred during regular use, for no apparent reasons.

I am using Windows Vista 64-bit, on a Gateway MD78 notebook, and the touchpad is a Synaptics Touchpad V6.3 on PS/ 2 port 3.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a **PS/2 to USB adapater**, and plugging it into a USB port, in case the PS/2 port is faulty.

You could also try a **System Restore** to take your system back to before the problem occurred.  Your documents, files and personal settings are unaffected by a System Restore, and it can be undone if required.